# Check if curl is installed and loaded

Tags: server, apache2, php, curl

I got log errors like these:

[image: ![enter image description here]

To solve this, I ran the below command and restarted the server.

```
sudo apt-get install php-curl
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Then I checked with code: `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` , I got this result:

[image]

Also I checked by running this code in a web browser:

```
echo 'Curl: ', function_exists('curl_init') ? 'Enabled' : 'Disabled';
```

In the web browser, it gave the result that it was `Disabled`.

Also when I checked by following the instructions at [Check to see if cURL is installed locally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13449054/check-to-see-if-curl-is-installed-locally), I got this result:

[image]

After doing all this I am still getting those log errors. Is curl loaded?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and apply code formatting.

Comment: @muru thanks for suggestion, i will follow your words......

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`apt-get install php7.0-curl` saved my time.

Comment: ahhahah Hilarious but thanks